# Mocking a method for unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, microsoft-fakes, shim

I want to mock the below method which takes parameters in order to do unit testing using fakes and shims. I am not having any idea it new for me. Any ideas would be helpful.

```
public string Renotify(int[] userIds)
{
     var notify = new NotificationPublisher();
     var message = "A request has been awaiting for your approval. Please check the application for details to approve the request ";
     var subject = "Logos Approval Notification";

     if (userIds.Length < 1)
         return "Please select users to notify";

     List<NotificationUser> userList = userIds.Select(t => new NotificationUser { userId = t }).ToList();
     notify.SendNotification(userList, message, subject);
     return "Success - Approvers Renotified";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't mock a method, per say, it wouldn't make sense, you mock interfaces which are used by the thing you want to test.

> Rather, you can, but I'm not convinced it's what you actually want.

e.g.

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly IBar _bar;

    public Foo(IBar bar)
    {
        _bar = bar;
    }

    public void MyMethodToTest()
    {
        // Some stuff
        _bar.SomethingToBeMocked();
        //some more stuff
    }
}
```

The `IBar` interface:

```
public IBar
{
    void SomethingToBeMocked();
}
```

You mock the interface `IBar`, and then set up an expected invocation on `IBar.SomethingToBeMocked()`